# AttributeError when running unittest sample in iPy Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am new to iPython and trying to help another developer get started and we are both hitting same issues.

We are attempting to run a python unittest sample in iPython from https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#basic-example
The code runs just fine from command line on windows and ubuntu without ANY modifications
Exact same code from iPy notebook generates following exception:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '/home/myuser/'
```

The filename is: `/home/myuser/example_unittest.ipynb`

I have noodled the iPython docs and google with no luck as of the moment. Any debugging tips, or clues to solving this issue are appreciated.

(full stack):

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-39bc0ec16f11> in <module>()
     28 
     29 if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 30     unittest.main()
     31 

/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.pyc in __init__(self, module, defaultTest, argv, testRunner, testLoader, exit, verbosity, failfast, catchbreak, buffer)
     92         self.testLoader = testLoader
     93         self.progName = os.path.basename(argv[0])
---> 94         self.parseArgs(argv)
     95         self.runTests()
     96 

/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.pyc in parseArgs(self, argv)
    147             else:
    148                 self.testNames = (self.defaultTest,)
--> 149             self.createTests()
    150         except getopt.error, msg:
    151             self.usageExit(msg)

/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.pyc in createTests(self)
    156         else:
    157             self.test = self.testLoader.loadTestsFromNames(self.testNames,
--> 158                                                            self.module)
    159 
    160     def _do_discovery(self, argv, Loader=loader.TestLoader):

/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.pyc in loadTestsFromNames(self, names, module)
    126         of string specifiers. See 'loadTestsFromName()'.
    127         """
--> 128         suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
    129         return self.suiteClass(suites)
    130 

/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.pyc in loadTestsFromName(self, name, module)
     98         obj = module
     99         for part in parts:
--> 100             parent, obj = obj, getattr(obj, part)
    101 
    102         if isinstance(obj, types.ModuleType):

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '/home/myuser/'
```

Comment: are you running exactly the code from the linked example?

Comment: Yes, the *exact* same code. Cut and pasted between website, notepad++ (for windows python), putty (for ubunty python), and the iPy notebook browser window.

Comment: check my answer below.  if it helps you with your question please accept it by clicking the green arrow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`unittest.main()` is primarily for command line execution.

In order to run a unittest in the ipython notebook, remove the `if __name__ == '__main__'` part of the code and, in a new cell, create a test suite and then run it using `TextTestRunner`,

```
suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestSequenceFunctions)
unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

Comment: you don't need to remove `if __name__ == '__main__'`, just change the `unittest.main()` command

Answer (score 9):

The reason you are getting that error because of unittest.main checks for arguments (sys.argv). It's what starts iPython or Jupyter.

Change your code to:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(argv=['first-arg-is-ignored'], exit=False)
```

In the notebook, you will also want to include `exit=False` to prevent unittest.main from trying to shutdown the kernel process:

Comment: first of all thank you for the beautiful blog. but i think i am still at the error..                               /usr/lib64/python2.7/unittest/case.pyc in __str__(self)
   1102     def __str__(self):
   1103         return "%s (%s)" % (strclass(self.__class__),
-> 1104                             self._testFunc.__name__)
   1105 
   1106     def __repr__(self):

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__name__'